# How do I create a new column with incrementing alphanumeric counter based on another column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Python/Pandas (of whatever is best way in python):

What if you want to increment a new column with values such as `A1,A2,A3...` in the rows (increasing on each row) based on if values are repeating in an existing column such that if the repeating in the existing column ends, column 2 jumps to `B1,B2,B3...` for the next repeating value (note if next value is not repeating it would simply be `B1` and then `C1`, etc)?

In other words, I have the existing column below and would like to simply add the new column as such:

| Existing Column | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | A1 |
| 12 | A2 |
| 12 | A3 |
| 13 | B1 |
| 13 | B2 |
| 14 | C1 |
| 15 | D1 |
| 15 | D2 |

and so forth....

I tried stuff like this which is not really close because

a) it does not start and stop counting based on existing column's values - it simply goes to the end with a single count.
b) there is another incrementing or keeping track involved because when one count is done A1,A2,A3 - the next count should start with B (B1, B2, B3) and this means the letter one is one needs to be kept track of for the new column.

```
list = []

nid = df['note_id']

for i in range(1, df.shape[0] + 1):   # gets the length of the DataFrame. 

if nid[df[i]] == nid[df[i+1]]:
list.append(f'A{i}') 

df['ID'] = list
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Use `get_column_letter` from `openpyxl` package if you have more than 26 letters:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

df['New Column'] = df['Existing Column'].ne(df['Existing Column'].shift()) \
                                        .cumsum().map(get_column_letter)

df['New Column'] += df.groupby('New Column').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print(df)

# Output
   Existing Column New Column
0               12         A1
1               12         A2
2               12         A3
3               13         B1
4               13         B2
5               14         C1
6               15         D1
7               15         D2
```

---

**Old answer**

Quick and dirty but it works only if you have less than 26 different values in `Existing Column`.

```
df['New Column'] = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['Existing Column'])[0]).add(65).map(chr)

df['New Column'] += df.groupby('New Column').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print(df)

# Output
   Existing Column New Column
0               12         A1
1               12         A2
2               12         A3
3               13         B1
4               13         B2
5               14         C1
6               15         D1
7               15         D2
```

Comment: See comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71580476/17242583) for more context.

Comment: @user2520842. I updated my answer, can you check it please? I think `openpyxl` is already installed if you already deal with excel file. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Also thank you @richardec for helping me clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at [pandas rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)? You could group by the existing column and then do a `rank(method='first')`. Then your existing column and the ranked column together could serve as the new column you want.

Comment: See comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71580476/17242583) for more context.